# grep: can't open /Data.cfg

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I am writing a Perl script to login to a remote machine from my local machine . The script logs into server and tries to grep data from a file Data.cfg.

```
               my $exp= new Expect();
               $command="ssh -l $LOGIN1 flx$First";
               $exp->spawn("$command");

               $exp->expect (5,

                  [ qr/\[$First\]->/i   => sub { my $exp = shift;

                    } ],
                  [qr/timeout/i=>
            sub {
                $exp->soft_close();
                print"Unable to login .\n";
                 }
                            ]);


              sleep 2;

           $dat=`grep -i num /Data.cfg | cut -d ":" -f 2`;
```

If the above command is done manually after login to remote machine it is working . However if i execute it from script i m getting an error  "grep: can't open /Data.cfg". I think it is trying to grep from local machine. Please suggest on how to achieve the solution.

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more from your code please? (Connection to the other server, executing the command and so on)

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea :)

Comment: give the full path name of `Data.cfg` file inside your script.

Comment: Data.cfg is in the remote machine Avi

Comment: you can try using the expect instance to send the command: `$exp->send("grep command")` and try to capture with `my $var = $exp->before()`

Comment: @salparadise I already tried that but its is giving the entire previuous expect result which i dont need .

Comment: I want to get only the last but one field of var . How will i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the file is on the remote host, you will want to try to either transfer the file locally and then grep, or grep it remotely. i would grep remotely:

```
$dat=`ssh -l $LOGIN1 'grep -i num /Data.cfg | cut -d ":" -f 2'`;
```